# MathJax help - negative fractions

Tags: support, mathjax

I  just want to know how you write negative fractions because I don't seem to understand why I am not able to make a fraction negative. Is it even possible?

Comment: You mean like $-\frac{3}{4}$ (`-\frac{3}{4}`), or something else?

Comment: I really don't understand your question... What do you mean by negative fractions? Is it what Daniel said or something else?

Comment: yes exactly what daniel said

Comment: This either belongs on the main site or on [TeX-LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To insert negative fractions (the way you said you want to insert them in $\LaTeX$ )just drop a minus sign in front of the command `\frac{}{}`.

That is if you want to produce $-\dfrac{5}{4}$ you can write: `-\frac{5}{4}`. You can also produce more complicated fractions like this:

$$\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}}$$

The code is `\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}}`.

Happy $\TeX$ing.